# How do I create a mock instance of http.ResponseWriter that returns an error on responseWriter.Write?

Tags: go

I moved all the response related Go code into a function

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
)

func WriteResponse(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, responseBody any, httpStatusCode int) {
    encodedResponseBody, err := json.Marshal(responseBody)

    if err != nil {
        // call logger

        apiResponse := NewErrorApiResponse() // create a struct for HTTP 500 responses
        encodedResponseBody, err = json.Marshal(apiResponse)

        responseWriter.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)

        if err != nil {
            // call logger

            return
        }

        _, err = responseWriter.Write(encodedResponseBody)

        if err != nil {
            // call logger
        }

        return
    }

    responseWriter.WriteHeader(httpStatusCode)
    _, err = responseWriter.Write(encodedResponseBody)

    if err != nil {
        // call logger
    }
}
```

and created tests for the following cases

- Success
- Error => `json.Marshal()` failed but not `responseWriter.Write()`

now I also want to create a test for the following case

> `json.Marshal()` failed, it tried to create an error response but `responseWriter.Write()` too so we can only log the error

So basically I started with

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestWriteResponse_NoResponseBody(testing *testing.T) {
    // TODO replace with mock returning error on .Write()
    responseWriter := httptest.NewRecorder()
    responseBody := make(chan int)

    WriteResponse(responseWriter, responseBody, http.StatusOK)

    assert.Equal(testing, http.StatusInternalServerError, responseWriter.Code, fmt.Sprintf("Expected status code %d, but got %d", http.StatusInternalServerError, responseWriter.Code))

    actualResponseBodyAsString := responseWriter.Body.String()

    assert.Equal(testing, "", actualResponseBodyAsString, fmt.Sprintf("Expected response body to be empty but got '%s'", actualResponseBodyAsString))
}
```

but the test fails because `responseWriter.Write()` is working fine. How do I force it to return an error so the response body will be empty?

Comment: I don't quite parse the question. Do you want to do _something_ so that an instance of `httptest.Recorder` fails on the 1st call to its `Write` method?

Comment: ResponseWrite is an interface so you can mock (using any mock tools https://github.com/vektra/mockery) it and inject an err in the write function or even implement an ErrResponseWrite struct that meets the interface specifications.

Comment: Don't go down that mocking rabbit hole. Make an actual call (use net/http/httptest.Server) tu a handler that simulates whatever condition you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just implement the interface:

```
type ResponseWriter interface {
    Header() Header
    Write([]byte) (int, error)
    WriteHeader(statusCode int)
}
```

so something like

```
type ErrorMockResponseWriter struct {
    Body io.ReadCloser
    Code int
}

func (e *ErrorMockResponseWriter) Header() http.Header {
    return http.Header{}
}

func (e *ErrorMockResponseWriter) Write(data []byte) (int, error){
    e.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(data)) 
    return 0, fmt.Errorf("always errors")
}

func (e *ErrorMockResponseWriter) WriteHeader(statusCode int) {
    e.Code = statusCode
}

func TestWriteResponse_NoResponseBody(testing *testing.T) {
    // TODO replace with mock returning error on .Write()
    responseWriter := ErrorMockResponseWriter()
    responseBody := make(chan int)

    WriteResponse(responseWriter, responseBody, http.StatusOK)

    assert.Equal(testing, http.StatusInternalServerError, responseWriter.Code, fmt.Sprintf("Expected status code %d, but got %d", http.StatusInternalServerError, responseWriter.Code))

    actualResponseBodyAsString := responseWriter.Body.String()

    assert.Equal(testing, "", actualResponseBodyAsString, fmt.Sprintf("Expected response body to be empty but got '%s'", actualResponseBodyAsString))
}
```